# How to get the login log in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2, I would want to record user's login log, including user id,ip address and timestamps. what should I do?

```
//migration code

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class LoginHistory extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('login_history', function (Blueprint $table) {

           $table->increments('id');

           $table->integer('user_id');

           $table->string('ip')->default(false);

           $table->timestamps();

           $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('login_history');
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.2, I would want to record user's login log, including user id,ip address and timestamps. what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything beyond merely creating a migration?

Comment: I have created a table 'login_history' in my database .And also created a model.Mode code is given below   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LoginHistory extends Model
{
    //
}

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events - documentation is your friend.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5 - Googling is also your friend.